# Красиво удалить элемент из массива

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1) Есть выпадающее меню, которое содержит элементы массива.
2) Есть условие, при котором нужно убирать определенные элементы массива.

Что-то типа этого:

```
if sum > 30
  element_of_dropmenu
else
 element_of_dropmenu.drop(1)
end
```

*(Пока логика такова что можно удалить только первый элемент, но если можно как то обращаться к объекту AR и удалять например по аттрибуту name, я буду рад узнать о такой возможности)*

`sum` - это хелпер, который считает сумму заказа в рублях.
`element_of_dropmenu` - массив, который содержит объекты AR с видами доставки.

Мне нужно выводить все элементы когда `sum>30`, и убирать один элемент когда `sum<30`

Есть ли возможность записать более красиво? (например используя delete_if, reject или drop_while).

**UPD**

Сам алгоритм должен работать так: пользователь добавляет в корзину товары. Пока в корзине товаров меньше чем на 3000р, то при оформлении заказа в типах доставки у него платные виды доставки.
Как только в корзине больше 3000р, то в оформлении товара, а выборе типа доставки должнен появиться пункт "бесплатная доставка".

Моя логика такова: Пункты меню я добавляю через админку. Они сразу попадают в оформление заказа на сайте, значит оттуда мне нужно убирать тип доставки при определенных условиях, что я и делаю.

Сейчас реализация такая

```
element_of_dropmenu.delete_if {|x| x.name == "free delivery" && basket_sum < 3000}
```

Comment: Можно просто не доставать ненужные элементы из БД

Comment: Но это же опять условие будет?

Comment: Это будет условие выборки `elemments_of_dropmenu = MyARModel.where('sum > ?', 30)`

Comment: Но он будет выводить только значения, где `sum > 30`, мне же нужно выводить все элементы когда `sum>30`, и убирать один элемент когда `sum<30`

Comment: У вас очень странно сформулирован алгоритм. Точнее, он понятен, но не очень понятно зачем выбрана такая реализация, возможно это можно сделать гораздо проще. Давайте с другой стороны, как этот алгоритм работет **на практике**, для пользователя? Можно с примером. И не в комментарии, а в сам вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, виды доставки это AR модель (например, `ShipmentMethod`).
Таким образом, нужно сделать следующее:

В класс `ShipmentMethod` нужно добавить флаг `for_free` (default: false), затем поменять на true те способы доставки, которые являются бесплатными для юзера.

Далее -- добавить scope в класс доставки:

```
class ShipmentMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
   FREE_SHIPMENT_LIMIT = 3000.0
   scope :by_sum, -> cart_sum { cart_sum > FREE_SHIPMENT_LIMIT ? where(for_free: true) : all }
end
```

теперь всякий раз при изменении корзины делаем ajax запрос и перерисовываем доставку, используя в качестве коллекции:

```
 ShipmentMethod.by_sum(current_cart_sum)
```

Вариант для ценителей ресурсов, трафика, дискового пространства, а также тонких натур и эстетов:

В класс  `ShipmentMethod` нужно добавить флаг `for_free` (default: false), затем поменять на true те способы доставки, которые являются бесплатными для юзера.

Далее, на форме хелпером рисуется сразу два **скрытых** контейнера с `<option></option>`, в одном коллекция строится на `ShipmentMethod.all`, во втором `ShipmentMethod.where(for_free: true)`, в этом случае все данные обновляются на стороне клиента -- проверяем текущую сумму в корзине и в зависимости от результата заполняем селект опциями из соответствующего контейнера.